# How do I install the newest version of glogg in Mythbuntu?

Tags: software-installation, software-center

I am new to linux, so I apologize if this is a ridiculous question. My system:

- Mythbuntu 14.04
- Xfce desktop

I wanted a gui to view/tail/filter multiple log files and after a brief web search decided on [glogg](http://glogg.bonnefon.org/index.html), which I installed from Ubuntu Software Center.

Software center installed version 0.9.2-1, however if I go to [the glogg website](http://glogg.bonnefon.org/index.html), I see that there is a version 1.0.3.

My question is how do I update to the latest version? I'm guessing I can learn how to compile the source, but is there any drawback to doing this vs just using the version from the software center?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is by no means a ridiculous question.
By the time an Ubuntu distribution is available, many developers have already released a newer version of their package. If you want to stay on top of the latest `glogg` release, compiling it from source appears to be the only option. However, it looks pretty straightforward. Download the zip file and enter the commands given. You may need to install a couple of dependencies first, though: `qmake-qt` as well as the `QT development libraries` are mentioned. I suggest you google around to find the packages that provide these.